# Почему надо обязательно использовать Try - catch

Tags: java, mysql

Есть программа на Java в которой допустим (к примеру) есть функция отображение списка категорий, который берется из базы данных через mysql запрос. Есть отдельная функция подключения к этой базе данных которая используется во всех функция - под названием Podkliucenije();

Вопрос: **Почему надо использовать try - catch в самих функциях где уже есть вызов функции подключения и почему без него выдает кучу ошибок, а с ним все работает?**

*Функция подключения*

```
Statement stmt;
Connection conn;

public void Podkliucenije()
    {
        // Podkliucenije k baze dannix
        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            String DB_URL = "jdbc:derby://localhost/db";
            String USER = "pavel";
            String PASS = "password";
            kategorijos.clear();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Podkliucheno");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Osibka podkliucenija k DB");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

*Пример одной из функции использования*

```
public ArrayList<Kategoriji> polucitSpisokKategorij()
    {
        try
        {
            Podkliucenije();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM kategoriji";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            while(rs.next())
            {
                String nazvanije = rs.getString(1);
                String opisanije = rs.getString("opisanije");
                System.out.println(nazvanije + " - " + opisanije);
                kategorijos.add(new Kategoriji(nazvanije, opisanije));
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Osibka podkliucenija k DB");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return kategorijos;
    }
```

Comment: В функции есть для того, что в функции, а снаружи для других функций, которые могут выбросить исключения. В частности, снаружи, для executeQuery. А вызов Podkliucenije можно и вне блока try сделать, хотя лучше оставить где он есть, а вот внутри него убрать try catch

Comment: О `try - catch` в любой книжке по Java написано.

Comment: В целом перехватывать исключения надо там где их удобнее всего обрабатывать, то есть как-то реагировать, что-то поправить, или изменить

Comment: @AlexanderChernin спасибо за разъяснения, теперь стало немного понятней

Comment: Хоть и не существенно, но немного странно в обсуждении программирования на Java слышать термин "функция" вместо "метод".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Почему надо обязательно использовать Try - catch

Использовать try-catch необязательно.
При вызове небезопасного метода у Вас всегда есть выбор:

- обернуть вызов опасного метода в try-catch
- пометить свой метод `throws SomeException`
  (*иногда данная опция недоступна при переопределении методов или имплементации интерфейсов*)

Более того, в Java есть исключения, которые необязательно перехватывать(на этом остановимся чуть позже).

`Exception` является наследником класса `Throwable`, классом описывающим все исключительные ситуации.
Вместе с `Exception` данный класс наследует класс `Error`.

- `Error` используется в ситуации, когда восстановление работы программы не представляется возможным. Такие исключительные ситуации генерируются самой JVM.
  Например: `OutOfMemeryError`(нехватка памяти), `StackOverflowError`(переполнение стека), `ThreadDeadError`(смерть потока), `VirtualMachineError`(Ошибка виртуальной машины)
- `Exception` же используется в ситуации, когда работу программы можно восстановить и продолжить.

Иерархия Throwable выглядит следующим образом:

```
              Throwable
              /      \
          Error     Exception
                        |
                RuntimeException
```

Throwable бывает двух типов:

- **checked** ( *проверяемые* )
  Данные исключения необходимо перехватывать, либо эскалировать исключение выше помечая свой метод `throws Exception`
  Пример: `IOException`, `SQLException`, etc.
- **unchecked** ( *непроверяемые* )
  Данные ситуации необязательно перехватывать и описывать в сигнатуре метода
  Пример: `NullPointerException`, `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, etc
  Также к unchecked относятся все ошибки(`Error`)

**В чём смысл**

При работе над методом, часто можно столкнуться с ситуацией когда при каком-либо условии может возникнуть ошибка и довольно часто на данном уровне Вы просто-напросто не можете оценить серьёзность данной ошибки в приложении и корректно обработать её. Насколько это серьёзно и как с этим дальше быть, как правило понятно на n-ное количество уровней выше.
Всё что Вы можете сделать это сообщить о возможной ошибке и возможно тем самым эскалировать данную проблему на тот уровень где она может быть разрешена.

Для этого вызывают примерно такой код:

```
throw new SomeException("У меня возникла проблема, которую я не могу решить!");
```

После того, как Вы выбросили исключение, Вам стоит поделиться с миром о том, что при вызове Вашего метода могут возникнуть проблемы.

Для этого в сигнатуру метода добавляется:

```
public void myMethod() throws SomeException{
    //...
    throw new SomeException("У меня возникла проблема, которую я не могу решить!");
    //...
}
```

После этого все будут знать, что после того как они вызовут Ваш метод  - они могут получить Exception  в лицо. 
"*Знание - сила!*"...а еще можно сказать "*Предупреждён, значит вооружен!*".

В общем когда Вы знаете, что имеете дело с потенциально опасным методом, Вы можете это учесть в своей логике и обработать ошибку, если Вы в данном месте в программе вправе это сделать.
Если же, Вы не можете корректно обработать ошибку в данном месте, то Вы помечаете свой метод, как выбрасывающий исключение и тем самым перекладываете ответственность на другие плечи.

На самом деле это очень важный момент. Самая распространенная ошибка, это перехват исключения раньше времени без корректной обработки(из-за боязни ошибок или простого непонимания данного механизма). В результате программа просто начинает вести себя непредсказуемым образом или просто не выполняет никаких действий, ожидаемых от нее пользователем. Так делать нельзя! Нужно всегда думать где стоит обработать исключение и как лучше всего на него отреагировать.

**Что происходит при выбросе исключения?**

1. При выбросе исключения работа программы прерывается.
2. JVM идёт обратно(снизу вверх) по стеку выполнения.

   - Если в данном стеке встречается точка, в которой данное исключение перехватывается, то JVM передаёт управление в данную точку.
   - Если в стеке никто не перехватил данное исключение, то работа заканчивается и в стандартный поток вывода выводится информация о произошедшем.

**В чём профит**

Помимо прерывания работы и возможности передачи управления в другую точку программы (за что эксепшены часто критикуются) они несут еще и очевидный информативный характер.

**Во-первых**: Вы можете оставить сообщение с описанием возникшей ошибки.
В будущем за него Вам могут быть благодарны многие незнакомцы, работающие с Вашим методом.

**Во-вторых**:  Как ни странно, но за стектрейс Вы также должны быть благодарны Throwable. Именно в момент создания Throwable сохраняется снимок стека выполнения текущего потока.

**В-третьих**:  Вы можете улучшить и гораздо более качественно описать возникшие при работе низкоуровневые исключения, исключениями более высокого уровня абстракции, сохранив при этом причинно-следственную связь, создав так называемые "цепочки ислючений".

Comment: хороший ответ, добавьте еще про Throwable и Error

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, обновил ответ

Comment: да, я видел, но больше уже плюсануть не могу =)

Comment: @Stranger Я могу плюсануть вместо тебя.

Comment: Плюсанул. Хороший ответ. Можно еще про блок finally добавить и подробнее про checked и unchecked.

Comment: @Inwar2006, сделаю сегодня как свободная минутка выпадет. А вообще тема очень обширная...я и про try-with-recources еще хотел добавить и комментарии про создание собственных исключений и комментарии про использование и блок критики

Comment: на хороший ответ порой уходит немало времени

Comment: Поддерживаю, продолжай. Тема полезная, особенно для начинающих.

Comment: @МихаилРебров еще раз огромное спасибо за разъяснение, смог грамотно переписать проект!